# Quantile Regression - What is the "bandwith"?

Tags: python, quantile-regression

I am trying to perform a Quantile Regression on hundreds of series.
From time to time, I have very small series that issue a warning.

Here's a sample code to reproduce :

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg

x=[[1, 1.7299e+04],
   [1, 1.7315e+04],
   [1, 1.7603e+04]]

y=[-0.764, -0.8191, -0.7919]

model = QuantReg(exog=np.array(x), endog=np.array(y))
result = model.fit(q=0.5)
```

Apparently, this comes down to the calculation of the bandwith using the `hall_sheather` method that returns a value `b` for my quantile `q` and a number of observations `n` such that $q + b > 1$ or $q - b < 0$.

This function is decreasing w.r.t. $n$, so I guess the small number of samples is the reason why it fails.

As another example : `hall_sheather(20, 0.8) = 0.21` so it would fail as well with 20 samples and $q = 0.8$.

---

I have very little background in stats, therefore I was wondering:

- if someone could explain me in a simple maneer where this bandwith parameter intervenes in the regression process ?
- if it seems logical to decrease $b$ if necessary such that $q + b < 1$ and $q - b > 0$?

Thank you!